# How do I test external DTO?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, dto

I want to test an **external DTO** that changes frequently.

ex:

I has a below javascript(json) file.

```
// javascript
const type User = {
    id: Number,
    name: String
}

// json
user: {
   id: Number,
   name: String,
}
```

At this time, the external API response changed.

```
// ex1) response (Add)
{
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    age: Number
}

// ex2) response (remove)
{
    id: Number
}

// and so on.
```

I want to get a failure result and change javascript file.

In this case, How do I test external DTO?

In other words, **I hope to check for changed properties**.

Comment: Create different test cases for `Add` and `Remove` operations and assert structure of the different responses. What stops you?

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume you have an api response and an User object/class

```
const apiResponse = '{ "id": 1, "name": "someName", "missingProperty": 1 }';
const response = JSON.parse(apiResponse);

const User = {
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    newProperty: Boolean,
}
```

This validation is for missing properties on response

```
for(const key in User) {
    if(!(key in response)) {
        console.error(`Missing property from response ${key}`);
    }
}
```

This validation is for missing properties on User model

```
for(const key in response) {
    if(key in User) {
        if(response[key].constructor === User[key]) {
            continue;
        }
        console.error(`${key} is not proper type, ${response[key].constructor} instead of ${User[key]}`);
    }
    console.error(`Missing property from model ${key}`);
}
```